# confused with spinner operation

Tags: android

I'm trying to do some calculation and spinner is one of the things that I used.

this is the best that I could do:

```
public class Price1 extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.price1);

    int price1 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("theprice");

    int price2 = calculateprice2(price1);

    TextView tvprice1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price1text2);
    tvprice1.setText(String.valueOf(price2));
}

private int calculateprice2(int price1) {
    Spinner sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    if (sp1.getSelectedItemPosition() == 1) {
        return (int) (price1 - (price1 / 10));
    } else if (sp1.getSelectedItemPosition() == 2) {
        return (int) (price1 - (price1 / 5));
    } else if (sp1.getSelectedItemPosition() == 3) {
        return (int) (price1 - ((price1 * 3) / 10));
    } else if (sp1.getSelectedItemPosition() == 4) {
        return (int) (price1 - ((price1 * 33) / 100));
    }

}
```

Read the code. I think you will Understand My goal (I hope you do, Because it's hard to explain when you have a very very bad English :-) )

and the problem is that I get this Error on "calculateprice2(int price2)":
"This method must return a result of type int"

I know my mistake is so silly, But I can't find it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the compilation error, `calculateprice2()` doesn't return anything if none of the `if` conditions matches. You'll probably need to return some reasonable default in that case, e.g. add

```
return 0;
```

at the end of the method.

To make it run the like you probably want, notice the following:

- Item positions start at index 0, not 1.
- `onCreate()` is only run when creating your activity. To make the method be run when the selection is changed, have a look at `setOnItemSelectedListener()`.

Comment: in this case i will always get 0 in TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this-

```
private int calculateprice2(float price20) {
    Spinner sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    Integer price1 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("theprice");
    if (sp1.getSelectedItemPosition() == 1) {
        return (int) (price1 - (price1 / 10));
    } else if (sp1.getSelectedItemPosition() == 2) {
        return (int) (price1 - (price1 / 5));
    } else if (sp1.getSelectedItemPosition() == 3) {
        return (int) (price1 - ((price1 * 3) / 10));
    } else if (sp1.getSelectedItemPosition() == 4) {
        return (int) (price1 - ((price1 * 33) / 100));
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: in this case i will always get 0 in TextView.

Comment: if none of the above condition satisfied then yes.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
else return 0;
```

at the end of `calculateprice2()` function. You see your function is not returning values in all cases.

Comment: in this case i will always get 0 in TextView.

Comment: That may be because of invalid value in price1 which is send as parameter. Adding else has nothing to do with it! Please check if getIntent().getExtras().getInt("theprice") is sending right value. Also see if spinner has more than 4 option.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see any problem in my syntax. It is returning 0 when no case is matched and 0 is int.

Comment: Oo god I look so foolish. Sorry! I have corrected it and thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a default return value if no one `if/else` statement is corrected. For example you could declare a `retVal` variable:

```
private int calculateprice2(int price1) {
    Spinner sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    int retVal = 0;
    if (sp1.getSelectedItemPosition() == 1) {
        return (int) (price1 - (price1 / 10));
    } else if (sp1.getSelectedItemPosition() == 2) {
        return (int) (price1 - (price1 / 5));
    } else if (sp1.getSelectedItemPosition() == 3) {
        return (int) (price1 - ((price1 * 3) / 10));
    } else if (sp1.getSelectedItemPosition() == 4) {
        return (int) (price1 - ((price1 * 33) / 100));
    }
    return retVal;

}
```

Comment: in this case i will always get 0 in TextView.